# Reducing the Tsunami impact using Nuclear bombs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy

I am a novice on this topic. However, I wonder if we use nuclear bombs against the tsunami, will it reduce the speed and impact of the tsunami. Is it possible to break the massive wall of waves using nuclear bombs? In other words, is it possible to create another opposite force which can neutralise/reduce the energy carried by Tsunami by creating an induced wave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tsunami dampening mechanisms](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6762/)

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the other; this is a more specific question about a specific choice of damping mechanism rather than a general "could we make a mechanism that works." Although an answer on that other question does address using explosives to do it.

Comment: @tpg2114 I totally agree. I am looking at the possiblity of creating another wave opposing the Tsunami which can neutralise it.

Comment: @tpg2114: the idea is the same for both questions: stopping a tsunami.

Comment: This particular idea, IMO, is a terrible one because (a) you're introducing huge amounts of bad radiation and (b) the nuclear blast will generate a wave of water headed towards the shoreline you are trying to protect.

Comment: @Hunter, you cannot oppose one wave with another wave. They pass through each other. Have you ever seen a demonstration of 2 points generating waves. There are always circular waves coming out from either point. If the waves interacted, the pattern would be different.

Comment: my knowledge on this subject/physics is very limited. I see your point. In layman terms, its not like one missile neutralising other one.

Comment: That's not entirely true. If you matched the wavelength exactly with a 90 degree phase offset, you can effectively cancel out the wave. It's called [Destructive Interference](http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~gibson/Notes/Section5_2/Sec5_2.htm) The downside is if you aren't exact then the waves may end up in phase at a point and you'd have two times the wave size which would be... bad.

Comment: Is it a practical idea to tune the time of bombing so that we have exactly 90 degree phase difference? @tpg2114

Comment: @Arafat Honestly? No part of this idea is practical so the timing is kind of the least of our concerns about practicality. Conceptually, yes it is possible to have two waves that cancel each other out.

Comment: I agree with with @KyleKanos but it would be fun to calculate the momentum of the tsunami wave and calculate how much momentum can be imparted in the opposite direction using an explosion. My hunch is that the wave will have massively more momentum than any man made blast. I guess you could also try an evaporate the tsunami :)

Comment: People tend to massively overestimate the energy output of nuclear weapons. What makes nuclear weapons work as weapons is that they concentrate a large amount of energy *in an extremely small area*. Natural phenomena like tsunamis and hurricanes have a small amount of energy per unit area but *enormous area*. The total energy content of a tsunami or hurricane is truly immense. You might as well be trying to stop a wave by throwing sand at it.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, though one should be careful not to over-compensate and underestimate the energy output. See, for example, the crater from the [Sedan shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedan_%28nuclear_test%29) of Operation Plowshare.

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't think this is a duplicate.  The issue of using UNDEX for wave cancellation / generation has been it's own topic of study which is not addressed at all either in the question or the answers in the "duplicate" link.

Answer (score 10):

It's not likely to effect the tsunami very much.

On the open ocean (where you would want to use the bombs), the wave height is not very much, so the air blast from the bombs would blow over the wave. The bombs would also create their own waves which would pass through the tsunami wave.

Near to shore, the tsunami wave would increase in height. The bombs would have a greater effect, but would destroy what you are trying to protect. (ooops)

Answer (score 6):

Also, the nuclear bombs would create a lot of radioactive waste, and the tsunami would create a highly effective way to disperse that waste.  Even if it would reduce the wind speeds, we probably don't want radioactive byproducts spread all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely. The wind can not transfer enough energy directly into building a wave big enough to cancel a tsunami.  The [detention would need to be underwater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_explosion) and create a displacement which would build a large wave, however this would be almost impossible to control to the precision required to cancel in incoming wave whose energy is usually only determined once it hits shore.

In addition there has been a [detailed study](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADA304244) that show explosion generated waves could not build a structured tsunami wave.  The wave resulting from an explosion (both shallow and deep water) would be similar to storm surge and just cause flooding.

Naturally people have thought of this before and have even tried to make it a weapon.  [Tsunami Bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsunami_bomb):

> The tests revealed that a single explosion would not produce a
>   tsunami, but concluded that a line of 2,000,000 kg (4,400,000 lb) of
>   explosives about 8 km (5.0 mi) off the coast could create a
>   destructive wave.

The odds are far more likely you would create many more problems with the explosions than actually reducing the tsunami wave.